# What is a Geodetic?

Tags: relativity

What is a geodetic? First I thought it was a typo (hehehe..). To me, the term "geodetic" is used to describe a curve that belongs to a congruence of geodesics...but, I also think I'm wrong. Surprisingly, I haven't found a definition of this term.

Here a reference. From Penrose-Rindler, SPINORS AND SPACE-TIME. Vol 2:

"Congruences of null curves in space-time - referred to here as null 
congruences - and especially of rays (geodetic* null curves), play an 
important part in electromagnetic and gravitational radiation theory and 
in the construction of exact solutions of Einstein's equations."

In the footnote, respecto to *, it says:

"The word 'geodetic' is used here consistently as the adjectival form of the noun 'geodesic'."

Don't know what that means though...

Comment: Can you include a reference to the use of this term? In relativity, it is almost certainly a typo or a confusion on the author's part. *Geodetic* is the adjective associated with *geodesy*, which is the branch of geography dealing with assigning coordinates to the Earth.

Comment: #Chris White. I already did

Comment: Nevermind... I was right. That is what "geodetic" means. From the same reference of Penrose:

"The condition for the congruence to be geodetic (i.e., for each of its members to be a geodesic) ..."